# Django : Create a dynamic path with BASE_DIR

Tags: python, django

I have a very simple question but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I would like to set the path to `.json file` like this :

```
with open(settings.BASE_DIR + '../../package.json') as package_json_file:
```

But i'm getting this issue :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/val/Bureau/Projets/APP/app/src../../package.json'
```

How I can define the path from `BASE_DIR` and come back to .json file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the issue in the error message: `src../../package.json` - there is a forward slash missing in `src..`.

Instead of concatenating strings, use `os.path.join` so that you don't have to worry about missing/duplicate forward slashes.

```
import os
os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '../../package.json')
```

Comment: You haven't said what `BASE_DIR` or your project layout is, but using `'..'` to go up a directory should work. Perhaps you have too many or too few `..`s. You can debug by checking `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '../../package.json')`

Answer (score 2):

First of all the problem in your code should be obvious: You are missing backslash between the `BASE_DIR` and the hard coded path you are adding. This this

`with open(settings.BASE_DIR + '/../../package.json') as package_json_file:`

should work (if the package is there of course).

However, to avoid such inconsistencies, it is better to explicitly use `os.path.join` to properly create paths, i.e you can use something like

`with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '..', '..', 'package.json')) as package_json_file:`

More info on join: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: Right I paste the bad part. But, if I wrote your code, it searches `package.json` in `/home/val/Bureau/Projets/OMCL/omcl/src`. package.json is placed in `/home/val/Bureau/Projets/OMCL/` that's why I would like to come back in my path